# Best way to copy new daily data from historical table in Databricks

Tags: databricks

Can you please review my method and advise me the best way to copy new daily data from historical fact table to another one.
I have 1 big parquet table let's call it "Table1" that somehow refreshes daily with some transactions with date.
I need to copy new data from "Table1" and keep it in my separated table let's call it "Table2" every day.
I did like this:

1. Read the historical table "Table1" and saved it in my place in my data lake as "Table2".
2. Next day I created a new notebook with code where I read "Table2", find MAX date and declare it as a variable "last_date".
3. I read "Table1" where is already new data and filter it by date > "last date" variable.
4. Save the filtered data to "Table2" with "append" mode and schedule this job daily.

Is that correct way in data engineering practice? Or there is a better and stable solution?

Comment: How it's updated? Just full rewrite of the data, or just append?

Comment: "Table1"? I think it's updated daily by "append", but I don't know definitely. I just can read that big table "Table1" and I want to take only data that I don't have in my "Table2". I could just overwrite my "Table2" with full copy of "Table1" but it takes a lot of time.